# XmlReader discards whitespace in between tags - how to keep them?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, whitespace, xmlreader

I read XML code, and I emit XML code. My end goal is to for some tags, rewrite the output so the transformed XML is pretty similar to the input XML, but not exactly.

However, the input XML has significant whitespace, but none of it survives in the output, it all disappears.

This is my code:

```
 Dim settings = New XmlReaderSettings With {
        .IgnoreComments = True,
        .IgnoreWhitespace = False,
        .Async = False,
        .CheckCharacters = False
    }

 Dim reader = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings)
 Dim output = ""

 While reader.Read()
     If reader.IsStartElement Then
          output += "<" + reader.Name + ">"
     ElseIf reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.EndElement
          output += "</" + reader.Name + ">"
     ElseIf reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text Then
            output += reader.Value
     ElseIf reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Whitespace Then
            output += reader.Value
     Else
            output += reader.Value
     End If              
End If
```

If I remove the `XmlNodeType.Text` and `XmlNodeType.Whitespace` checks, the output is still the same.

Input:

```
<html><body><span>some text</span> <span>more text</span></body></html>
```

Output:

```
<html><body><span>some text</span><span>more text</span></body></html>
```

Can XmlReader somehow keep the whitespace outside of tags and not discard it?

Of course, I would have the same problem if the code was written in C#

Comment: where is the `reader` created, and are you applying the `settings`? It isn't shown in your code example i.e. `XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFile, settings)`

Comment: @MadsHansen I forget that line, added it

Comment: XML specification doesn't require white spaces.  Try using an XmlReaderSetting :            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
           settings.IgnoreWhitespace = false;

Comment: @jdweng but that's exactly what the code above does...